# App rejected: React Native app crashed when opening image crop picker

Tags: react-native, app-store, crash-reports

**No issues or crashes with app on build mode and in 3 different devices.**

App got rejected by App Store review.

**Rejection reason:** The app crashed when we selected the image uploader.

---

Now I'm need guidance trying to figure out what the cause of the crash is because I can't recreate it. And before considering using another image picker package I would like to try to make sense of this crash first.

---

**Additional Information**

"react-native": "0.57.1",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.3",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.14"

---

Library used: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Code used (Is anything missing?):

```
openPhotoPicker() {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()
  const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob
  const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs
  window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest
  window.Blob = Blob
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    compressImageMaxWidth: 800,
    compressImageMaxHeight: 800,
    compressImageQuality: 0.8,
    cropping: true,
    smartAlbums: ['UserLibrary', 'Favorites'],
    mediaType: 'photo'
  }).then(image => {
    const imagePath = image.path
    let uploadBlob = null
    const imageRef = firebase.storage()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/progress`)
      .child(`${toJSONLocal(this.state.newDate)}.jpg`)
    let mime = 'image/jpg'
    fs.readFile(imagePath, 'base64')
      .then((data) => {
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      uploadBlob = blob
      return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
    })
    .then(() => {
      uploadBlob.close()
      return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
    })
    .then((url) => {
      let obj = {}
      obj["progressPhoto"] = url
      this.setState(obj)
      this.addPhotoDatabase() // Photo uploaded to firebase storage is also uploaded to database so it can be referenced.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Here's the symbolicated crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) 
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY 
Triggered by Thread:  1 

Application Specific Information: 
abort() called 

Last Exception Backtrace: 
0   CoreFoundation                0x1b64cf518 __exceptionPreprocess + 228 
1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x1b56aa9f8 objc_exception_throw + 55 
2   MyApp                         0x10048a3f8 RCTFatal + 222200 (RCTAssert.m:132) 
3   MyApp                         0x100486938 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 207160 (RCTExceptionsManager.m:58) 
4   CoreFoundation                0x1b64d6ba0 __invoking___ + 143 
5   CoreFoundation                0x1b63b8c90 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 291 
6   CoreFoundation                0x1b63b98c4 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 59 
7   MyApp                         0x10049eaa0 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 305824 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:550) 
8   MyApp                         0x1004e5750 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 595792 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104) 
9   MyApp                         0x1004e54ac invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 595116 (RCTNativeModule.mm:71) 
10  libdispatch.dylib             0x1b5f0fa38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23 
11  libdispatch.dylib             0x1b5f107d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 15 
12  libdispatch.dylib             0x1b5eb9320 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 591 
13  libdispatch.dylib             0x1b5eb9e3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 427 
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x1b5ec24a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 595 
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1b60f0114 _pthread_wqthread + 303 
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1b60f2cd4 start_wqthread + 3 


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue 
Thread 1 Crashed: 
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001b606d0dc __pthread_kill + 8 
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001b60e6094 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380 
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00000001b5fc6ea8 abort + 140 
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001b5693788 __cxa_bad_cast + 0 
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001b5693934 default_unexpected_handler+ 6452 () + 0 
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00000001b56aae00 _objc_terminate+ 24064 () + 124 
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001b569f838 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 55352 ()) + 16 
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001b569f8c4 std::terminate+ 55492 () + 84 
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001b5f107e8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001b5eb9320 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592 
10  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001b5eb9e3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428 
11  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001b5ec24a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596 
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001b60f0114 _pthread_wqthread + 304 
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001b60f2cd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: have you tried testing using different emulators?? maybe one of them could reproduce the issue.

Comment: try updating.. https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/releases/tag/v0.10.15

Comment: Haven't updated any libraries yet but I will be doing so. Was hoping someone would be able to look at the crash report and my code to see if there was something specific that was causing the crash. Even when I update the libraries I most likely won't be able to reproduce the issue, that's why I was hoping the info I provided would help in pinpointing the issue.